# AIX Unix Replicate data referencing a variable

Tags: text-processing

I am using unix on AIX.

I want to know if there is a way in which I can replicate rows of data either within an existing file or reading from *file a* and results into *file b*, or within a temp table by a "variable" number of times.

Example with 2 rows.

```
Product Number|Pick Qty|Unit of Issue|
13011|5|C|
566666|2|I|
```

The result I am after, is to use the Pick Qty value as the multiplying variable.
(This Pick Qty value will always be within the same position within the file, or column within a table.)

```
13011|5|C|
13011|5|C|
13011|5|C|
13011|5|C|
13011|5|C|
566666|2|I|
566666|2|I|
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk -F\| 'NR==1 {print} NR>1{for(i=$2;i>0;i--) print}' file_a > file_b
```

where

- `-F\|` use `|` as separator (you must escape it)
- `NR==1 {print}` print header (first line)
- `NR>1{for(i=$2;i>0;i--) print}` for all remaining line, print then `$2` time.